# Limit Evaluation of $a^x$ for negative a

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}{x(-2)^x}$$
Does it exist or not?

My work: For positive $a$ it is easy to handle the term $a^x$ because the term $\ln(a)$ exists but I am unable to deduce some concrete understanding for negative $a$ value.

Comment: $a^x$ has no meaning for $a \lt 0$ when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: Isn't there any approximation available even when x->0 using exponential relations? I mean I am not aware of such things but curious to know how can such limit be evaluated by any means

Comment: As $a^x= e^{x \ln a}$, you can use Taylor expansion of the exponential around the origin.

Comment: Yes the main concern for me is does the relation even holds for let's say a=-3?

Comment: It holds for any $a \gt0$.

Comment: The limit only would exist if $(-2)^x$ were defined in a neighborhood of $x=0$ , which is not the case. Not even the limit from the right exists.